# Error ORA-00936 in Laravel Eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, oracle, eloquent

First of all, excuse my English,

I am using oracle database
I have one to one relationship between two models

```
Class A
{
public function ARelation{
    return $this->hasOne(B::class,’Table_A_ID’,’id’);
}}
Class B
{

public function BRelation{

    return $this->belongsTo(A::class,’Table_A_ID’,’id’);
}}
```

Now when i try

```
A::with(’Arelation’)->get();
```

I get the following error

> PHP warning oci_execute():ORA-00936: missing expression in
>   path/vendor/yajra/laravel-pdo-via-oci8/src/Pdo/oci8/statement.php on
>   line 159 Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message Error Code 
>   :936 Error message: ORA-00936: missing expression  Position : 74
>   Statement: select * from “Table_B” where (”Table_B”.”Table_A_ID” in
>   (0,1,2,3,4 to 3999) or or or or ”Table_B”.”Table_A_ID” in
>   (4000,4001,4002, to 4999)or or or this keep getting repeated until it reach
>   the last ID in my data which is 10K  Bindings : [] select * from “Table_B”
>   where (”Table_B”.”Table_A_ID” in (0,1,2,3,4 to 3999) or or or or
>   ”Table_B”.”Table_A_ID” in (4000,4001,4002, to 4999) or or or this keep getting
>   repeated until it reach the last ID in my data which is 10K

based on my search and all the tutorials I have seen this code is supposed to run but it doesn’t work in my case for an unknown reason

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have a typo error. It must be

```
A::with(’Arelation’)->get();
```

It seems that calling of each relationship got into infinite. Like after calling the Arelation it would call again BRelation and Arelation again to BRelation again in again. I suspect here that maybe on your class B, you had appended the BRelation which made the result like that.

Comment: Thanks, i will edit my question, but this typo is not in the original code. 
I wrote this question letter by letter.